# How to get the notification when someone edits their answer?

Tags: feature-request

Yesterday I posted a post [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/173481/what-hypothesis-should-i-raise-when-literature-goes-for-two-sides?noredirect=1#comment466717_173481). I saw that @Buffy edited his answer but I did not receive the notification about the edited answer.

**Is there any way to get the notification in the inbox when an answer in your post is edited?**

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Follow feature below the answer.

See [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/401068) for more information.

Comment: Hi @Bryan, I am wondering if there is any option that I can follow every question that I ask rather than hitting the " **follow** " button at the bottom left corner of every question

Comment: @NoviceMindset No, there is no feature like that in the SE software. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/401068 has some more info about what triggers a notification and what doesn't; the one you ask about is included in the list of "things you might think triggers a notification but doesn't". It's likely someone else has requested what you have on the main meta (meta.stackexchange.com), but like Massimo I'm on mobile right now and it's a bit of a pain to search. Otherwise you could make your own feature request, but I think you'll probably just be pointed back to the Follow feature.

Comment: @NoviceMindset And in case you decide to post your own feature request, beware that the main meta is a kind of a minefield for new users where one might get heavily downvoted in case of a duplicate request.

Comment: Yeah, that's an important caution. A lot of people post there without doing their homework and it makes the locals a bit restless and short to frustration.

Comment: I thought  the OP on a question got a flag for every answer, answer edit, and comment on their question as well as comments to answers. Not so?

Comment: @Buffy No, the OP is notified neither of answer edits nor of comments to answers.